# Lemon curd bonbons

Tags: chocolate

When trying to cap my lemon curd bonbons the chocolate would not set up/seal?Any help is appreciated. Wondering if consistency of curd is not firm enough? Maybe the water portion in it from the fresh lemon
Juice?

Comment: Welcome! Can you add a few more details, what exactly are you making, is there for example a recipe that would help the community understand what’s happening?

Comment: As Stephie said, more information would be helpful. A picture can help us understand how you're trying to seal them with chocolate - this may be a language issue, but in English, I've only seen "bonbon" refer to hard sugar candy, not to something that contains lemon curd and chocolate (which may be normal in French).

Answer (score 1):

Lemon curd does not set the way that ganache does. The fat in ganache (cocoa butter) crystalizes, and this is how ganache sets. But lemon curd is a type of gel made from the (denatured) proteins in the egg yolk, and the phospholipids in the yolk also help emulsify the curd. It is a very different mechanism, and they are not going to have the same consistency.

Typically, bonbons (aka pralines) are made with a ganache center or some other center that does not need to be refrigerated so it is shelf stable. If you're actually making lemon curd, that is probably not the best idea for a bonbon as it needs to be kept refrigerated. You might make a lemon filling that is not curd. Sugar is highly hygroscopic and hydrophilic, and the high amount of sugar in bonbon fillings typically is designed to prevent bacterial growth when stored at room temperature. (Sugar greatly lowers the Aw.)